# Drawing a graph with Swing: general approach

Tags: java, swing, graph, drawing

Suppose I have a graph composed of nodes and edges, and I want to draw it in a Swing app.
I'm not a Swing programmer, but as far as I know, I see two approaches:

1. draw the entire graph as a component
2. draw each node and edge as a single component

I've seen an application doing the first. To drag a node, drawn as a circle, the app checks what is the nearest node to the clicked point. It seems to me that this is not much efficient.
Is the second approach feasible? And which one should be followed, and why?

Comment: there are some free Graphs (google for that) and with excelent responses on this forum (for example JFreeGraphs), non-Free has variable Docs&Supports&Forum about Q&A by onwers web-sites...

Comment: why reinventing the wheel? Apart from the already suggested JGraph there's the my favourite JUNG framework

Comment: I'm writing a simply library in Javascript, and I was looking at libraries that could "inspire" me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We write and maintain [`JGraph`](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) and after 10 years of doing so we still have a single flyweight renderer that's shared to draw all cells. The reason is the memory cost of a component per cell. The disadvantage is that you need to deal with refreshing and event handling yourself, but it's not that bad.

We've had the coversation many many times, always the same conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Either approach is feasible, depending on the requirements. [`GraphPanel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) is a simple example of a single component, while [`JGraph`](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) is a more flexible library that uses the [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) for efficient rendering.

Comment: I took a quick glance at the source code of JGraph, and it seems to me that it uses the *first* approach, as for "component" I meant "a Swing component" and if I'm right JGraph has a single component which draws the cells containing the nodes and the edges

Comment: I see your point; I've tried to clarify the wording. The flyweight pattern also appears in `JTable` renderers and editors.